# Настройка кодировки, при отправке сообщения на e-mail

Tags: php

Написал такой вот скриптик восстановления пароля (не полностью):

```
$login = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['login']));
$mail = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['mail']));
$send = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['send']));

if($send){
if(strlen($login) > 0){
if(strlen($mail) > 0){
$rovw = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$login'     AND email='$mail' "));
if($rovw['username'] == $login || $rovw['mail'] == $mail){

if(mail($mail,'Новый пароль','Вы удачно поменяли пароль, теперь он имеет такое        значение:'))
{ print "";}
else
{ print "";}


echo "<script>alert('Если данные были введены верно, то новый пароль отправлен на  Имейл.');</script>";
}
else{
echo "<script>alert('Если данные были введены верно, то новый пароль отправлен на    Имейл.');</script>";
}
}
else{
echo "<script>alert('Вы не ввели Имейл');</script>";
}
}
else{
echo "<script>alert('Вы не ввели Логин!');</script>";
}
}else{}
```

Скрипт работает хорошо и сообщение приходит на почту, но приходит вот таким:

```
п▓я▀ я┐п╢п╟я┤п╫п╬ п©п╬п╪п╣п╫я▐п╩п╦ п©п╟я─п╬п╩я▄, я┌п╣п©п╣я─я▄ п╬п╫ п╦п╪п╣п╣я┌ я┌п╟п╨п╬п╣ п╥п╫п╟я┤п╣п╫п╦п╣:
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно изменить?

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понял, Вы формируете сообщение в `utf-8`.

Следовательно, отправлять нужно так:

```
mail($mail,'Новый пароль','Вы удачно поменяли пароль, теперь он имеет такое        значение:', "Content-Type: text/plain; charset='UTF-8'");
```

Следует также заметить, что на почту никакого пароля не придет :)

Comment: Да спасибо, я просто написал скрипт обработки =)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема с кодировкой. Преобразовывайте строку в 1251 перед отправкой.